# Subtracting one array from another

Tags: php, arrays

I want to subtract one array from another .

for example I have 2 arrays.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 251
    [1] => 251
    [2] => 130
)


 Array
    (
        [0] => 13
        [1] => 13
        [2] => 50
    )
```

The resulting array has to be

```
Array
    (
        [0] => 238
        [1] => 238
        [2] => 80
    )
```

Any sort of help on this is appreciated .

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP subtract array values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9118150/php-subtract-array-values)

Comment: used array_map or array_walk on these to avoid foreach and conserved memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
$array1  = array(251, 251, 130);
$array2  = array( 13,  13,  50);
$res     = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($array1);$i++){
   $res[$i] = $array1[$i]-$array2[$i];
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
```

Comment: Just to note it will throw a warning if key ($i) doesn't exist in `$array2`.

Comment: Yeah...Both array should be of same length

Comment: I get an error saying.. Notice: Undefined index: translationTool

Comment: @Justin - so what is translationTool? Something important that you forgot to mention in your question?

Comment: Sorry . It was throwing error due to some other fault . Its working . Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Solution using [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map):

```
function subtract($a, $b) {
  return $a - $b;
}

$arrayA = array(251, 251, 130);
$arrayB = array( 13,  13,  50);
$output = array_map('subtract', $arrayA, $arrayB);
```

**If the input arrays have different dimensions, it will still work.**

Solution with simple foreach loop:

```
$arrayA = array(251, 251, 130);
$arrayB = array( 13,  13,  50);
$output = array();

for ( $i = 0; $i < size($arrayA); ++$i ) {
  $output[] = $arrayA[$i] - $arrayB[$i];
}
```

Comment: I get an error saying Notice: Undefined index: translationTool

Comment: There is no `translationTool`. How do you use it ?

Answer (score 1):

In one line $array3 = $array1 - $array2 is

```
$array3 = array_intersect($array1, array_diff($array1, $array2));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function subArray($arr1, $arr2) {
  $res = array();
  foreach ($arr1 as $key => $value) {
    $res[$key] = $arr2[$key] - $arr1[$key];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr1 = array(251, 251, 130);
$arr2 = array( 13,  13,  50);
$result_array = array();

for ( $i = 0; $i < size($arr1); ++$i ) {
  $result_array [] = $arr1[$i] - $arr2[$i];
}

print_r($result_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have  one sample code here

```
    function array_sub_values($arr1, $arr2)
{
    $result = array();
    foreach ($arr1 as $k => $val)
        $result[] = $val - $arr2[$k];
    return $result;
}
```

So you can do:

```
$arr1 = array(1, 2, 3);
$arr2 = array(0, 0, 1);

$arr3 = array_sub_values($arr1, $arr2);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you dont want to destroy the arrays then:-

1. create duplicate of array 1
2. loop through array
3. IF same key exists in array 2, then subtract the value from current value

code:

```
$array3=array1;
while(list($key,$value)=each($array3))
{
    if(isset($array2[$key])) $array3[$key]-=$array2[$key];
}
```