# How to code in php of calculating the difference?

Tags: php

Can someone help me how to code the differences of the temperature . 
For example, in channel one the difference should be 3 . channel two should be 10, channel three should be 2. Also, if I change the temperature to negative. how should I code it ? HELP

```
<?php
$a1=array(
"channelOne"=>"45",
"channelTwo"=>"100",
"channelThree"=>"20"

);

foreach($a1 as $Name=>$Temperature) {
echo "Channel_Name"."<br>".$Name."<br>"."Actual_Temperature"."<br>".$Temperature."<br>";

}

$a2=array(
"channelOne"=>"48",
"channelTwo"=>"90",
"channelThree"=>"22"
);

foreach($a2 as $Name=>$Temperature_Now) {
echo "Channel_Name"."<br>".$Name."<br>"."Temperature_Now"."<br>".$Temperature_Now."<br>";

}

?>
```

Comment: I assume you have a calculator with the minus key. Now there is a thought

Comment: `foreach($a1 as $channel => $value) { $difference = $value - $a2[$key]; ... do something with $difference }

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9118150/php-subtract-array-values

Answer (score 0):

you can use the array_map function for this

```
$a1=array(
"channelOne"=>"45",
"channelTwo"=>"100",
"channelThree"=>"20"
);
$a2=array(
"channelOne"=>"48",
"channelTwo"=>"90",
"channelThree"=>"22"
);

$diff = array_map(
    function ($a1, $a2)
    {
        return abs($a1-$a2);
    }, $a1,$a2
);
print_r($diff);
```

Fiddle:http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/cig-k2n

and you want to keep the keys intact you can use array_walk like this.

```
$a1=array(
"channelOne"=>"45",
"channelTwo"=>"100",
"channelThree"=>"20"
);
$a2=array(
"channelOne"=>"48",
"channelTwo"=>"90",
"channelThree"=>"22"
);

array_walk($a1,
function (&$v, $k) use ($a1,$a2)
{
    $v = abs($a1[$k]-$a2[$k]);
});
print_r($a1);
```

Fiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/njd-qeh

Reference:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

Comment: Thanks. But I want write these results to text file . how to do that ? I am new to php