# How to conditionally perform subtraction between corresponding elements from two arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, null, conditional-statements, subtraction

I am trying to subtract the values from two arrays. I have also tried with an `if` condition, `null` value, `foreach` and a lot other methods like `array_filter`, but I failed.

`$exit_price` contains:

```
array (
    0 => 2205,
    1 => 6680,
    2 => 50351,
    3 => 100,
    4 => 100,
    5 => 1200,
    6 => 900,
    7 => 234,
    8 => 2342,
    9 => 45654
)
```

`$stoploss` contains:

```
array (
    0 => null,
    1 => null,
    2 => null,
    3 => null,
    4 => null,
    5 => null,
    6 => 145300,
    7 => null,
    8 => null,
    9 => 12222
)
```

How can I get the following result by subtracting `$stoploss` from `$exit_price` while omitting results where the `$stoploss` value is `null`?

Expected result:

```
array (
    6 => -144400,
    9 => 33432
)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this same question was asked last week, but I cant find it. Anyways, use a for loop and compare the value to null, if it's not, add it to a new array

Comment: I'm not seeing how the first array is being used here, can you give a little more information?

Comment: I am unable to solve this by for loop. @ChadK

Comment: I just want to sub-traction between `$exit_price` and  `$stoploss` and want to get result in array with skipping null value. @RossWilson

Comment: So this is a class project? Maybe check out this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9118150/php-subtract-array-values

Comment: i have added clear information on question again updatated.

Comment: @ChadK I dont want to subtraction null value. it should be skip in calculation.

Comment: Use array_filter after you subtract the two. In the other Stack Overflow post I linked, there is a closure called $subtracted. Modify it to where it doesn't subtract if one of the values is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply iterate the first array and check the corresponding element in the second for a `null` value.  If the value is not null, perform the subtraction and store the difference in a new "results" array using the current key.

```
$results = [];

foreach ($stoploss as $key => $value) {
    if (!is_null($value)) {
        $results[$key] = $exit_price[$key] - $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe some may say it less elegant but it is actually the best way to proceed. It is more fast than array_map+array_filter...

Answer (score 2):

One way could be to pass both arrays to [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php).

Inside array_map check if the current item of  `stoploss` is not null. If it is not, then do the subtraction.

After the array_map use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to remove the null values:

```
$exit_price = [
    0 => 2205,
    1 => 6680,
    2 => 50351,
    3 => 100,
    4 => 100,
    5 => 1200,
    6 => 900,
    7 => 234,
    8 => 2342,
    9 => 45654
];
$stoploss = [
    0 => null,
     1 => null,
     2 => null,
     3 => null,
     4 => null,
     5 => null,
     6 => 145300,
     7 => null,
     8 => null,
     9 => 12222
];

$result = array_map(function ($x, $y) {
    if (null !== $y) {
        return $x - $y;
    }
    return null;

}, $exit_price, $stoploss);

print_r(array_filter($result, function ($z) {
    return null !== $z;
}));
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/foURE)

Comment: @mickmackusa Thank you, you are right. I have updated the array_filter to return true if the value is not `null`.